# writing flexible regex expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-tesseract

I am trying to write a program that reads text from screenshots and then identifies various PII from it. Using pytesseract to read in the text, I am trying to write regex for urls, email IDs etc. Here is an example of a function which takes in a string and returns `True` email IDs and `False` otherwise:

```
def email_regex(text):
    pattern = compile(r"\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
    return bool(pattern.match(text))
```

This function works well for all email IDs in a proper format(abc@xyz.dd), but since the input to the function is text read in from pytesseract, the text is not guaranteed to be properly formatted. My function returns `False` for `abc@xyzdd`. I'm running into the same issues with URL regex,domain name regex etc. Is there a way to make my regex expressions more robust to reading in errors from pytesseract?

I have tried following the accepted solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540062/fuzzy-regex-e-g-e-2-correct-usage-in-python) answer, but that leads to the regex functions returning `True` for random words as well. Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT :- Here are my url and domain regexs, where I'm running into the same problem as my email regex. Any help with these will be very useful for me.

````
    pattern = compile(r'\b(((([a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,86} 
    [a-zA-Z0-9]))\.(([a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,73}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.(([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,25})))|((([a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,162}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.(([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,25}))))\b', re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.match(text)```


  def url_regex(text):
    pattern = compile(r'(http|https://)?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+)', re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.match(text)
````

Comment: Where do you want draw the line? Isn't something like `.+@[^@]+` sufficient, matching everything that has exactly one @ symbol in the middle? If your OCR fails to recognize the @ symbol correctly, there's little hope that the result is easily recognizable as an email address.

Comment: something like ```abc@xyzcom``` should be acceptable. A missing @ is going to be difficult to manage, as you pointed out. Similarly, ```httyis://www.facebook.com``` should be acceptable to the url_regex...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding some flags, such as ignorecase and DOTALL for newlines:

```
# Match email ID:
my_pattern = compile(r"^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]?\w{2,3}$", re.I, re.S)
```

Match URLs:

https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611

Comment: can you help me with an example here, where adding a flag takes care of the case I've outlined in the body of the question?

Comment: Yes: The character sets currently checks lower case letters: a-z, which won't find mails like aBc@xyZ.dD, right ?

Comment: So adding the re.I flag will give more robustness

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the tip. Is there anything I can do to make the regex I've posted in the question for example more robust against edge cases like I've described in the question?

Comment: Solving the "False" return value for the "abc@xyzdd" email ID could be done by making the . (dot) optional, which can be done with the quantifier "?" (zero or one occurrences), trailing the \. (dot-character)

Comment: this was helpful. Can you edit your answer so that I can select it as the accepted answer? Also, if you could look at the updated question body and have a look at the other functions as well, I'd be grateful